# WhereParameter is not working for dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net

My Table structure

**`Courses`**

- `Id`
- `Description`

**`Subjects`**

- `Id`
- `Description`
- `Courses`  (Relation to Courses table).

My code as follows

```
  td>
   <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourses" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqCourses"
       DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id"/>
   <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqCourses" runat="server"
       ContextTypeName= "DataAccess.SchoolStudyDataContext"  Select="new (Description, Id)"
       TableName="Courses" />
</td>
 <td align="left" valign="top" class="style5" style="width: 124px">
 <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlSubjects" runat="server" DataSourceID="LinqSubjects" 
      DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id"/>
      <asp:LinqDataSource ID="LinqSubjects" runat="server" 
     ContextTypeName= "DataAccess.SchoolStudyDataContext"  Select="new (Description,Courses,Id)"
     TableName="Subjects" Where="Courses == @Id" />
      <WhereParameters>
           asp:ControlParameter ControlID="ddlCourses" Name="Id"
           PropertyName="SelectedValue"  Type="Int32" />
     </WherePrameters>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCourses" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1"
   DataTextField="Description" DataValueField="Id"/> 

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProjectConnectionString %>" 

    SelectCommand="SELECT [Description],[Courses],[Id] FROM [table_name] WHERE ([Courses ] = @Courses ) ">
    <SelectParameters>

        <asp:Parameter  Name="Courses" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

This is not a exact answer but this might help i guess

Answer (score 0):

Your Where Property is wrong. Change this (`==`):

```
  Where="Courses == @Id" />
```

To this (`=`):

```
 Where="Courses = @Id" />
```

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linqdatasource.where%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)